# What is the difference between Bing Map Api's Search vs Geocode services?

Tags: silverlight, geocode, bing-maps

I ask this because the interactive SDK sample for these two features appear to do the exact same thing with same behavior as well.

anyone know?

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/default.htm#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.Services.Geocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though at first they look like the same thing, there is some difference between how both services are implementer. Technically Geoocode tries to match the search string in the addresses database.But the search feature is more comprehensive. The search feature is more managed and is a super set of geocode. 
For example in search feature if you try typing 'pizza' it shows restaurants serving pizza. but if you try typing pizza in geocode example it takes some where in russia where address sounds like pizza!

Hope that helps you in grasping the subtle difference. Let me know if you need more clear explaination.